# Symfony 5 (Doctrine 2.9), Doctrine does not generate migration for a ManyToOne self-referencing relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using **Symfony 5** with **Doctrine 2.9** on a project and I need to make a ManyToOne relation on the same Table (Self-referencing).

For that purpose, I used the following link https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/association-mapping.html

For a One-To-Many, Self-referencing relation, it says that:

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Category
{
    // ...
    /**
     * One Category has Many Categories.
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * Many Categories have One Category.
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Thanks to that I can update my entity with `php bin/console make:entity` and add the needed relations.

The problem is, when my entity is updated with the new relations, I make a `php bin/console make:migration` to generate the desired migration, no changes are detected.

That does not really matter because I can generate by hand the migration, but when I update my table by hand, by adding the foreign key and the associated index, on the next migration, doctrine suggests me to delete the foreign key, index and attribute (parent_id).

Would there be solutions to overcome this problem?

Thanks for you time,

Guillaume

Comment: When using migration, you should not try to update the schema by hand, because doctrine will try to overwrite it next migration. Try updating your `$parent`, with only: `* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Category::class, inversedBy="children")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, by putting this: `/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;` in my associated entity, i still dont have migration generated. I don't know if symfony migration maker has difficulties when we try to generate migration with self-referencing relation. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder, I have similar self referencing association and I have no issue, what is your doctrine version & maker bundle ?

Comment: Do you have some cache on Doctrine? Could you add your configs files to your question (cache.yaml, doctrine.yaml, doctrine_migrations.yaml ...)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, like @qdequippe said, I clear the cache of Doctrine and it worked. Previously I only did`php bin/console cache:clear`. Thanks for your time. Can I add the answer below or do you want to add it (I will upvote you for help if you want to ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clean your Doctrine cache (it depend of your configuration) with this command:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```